# TYPO3 FAL FileStorageIndexingTask with Umlauts in file names

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typo3-6.2.x, fal

In TYPO3 6.2.11, I have set

```
[SYS][UTF8filesystem] = 1
[SYS][systemLocale] = de_DE.UTF-8
```

The (CentOS) filesystem as well as the Filelist module recognize and display the files properly.

But when I run `TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\FileStorageIndexingTask` via the scheduler, it marks files containing special characters in their filename as `missing = 1`.

Is there some other required setting for FAL to be able to process UTF8-Filenames?
Or could this be something server-side?

Comment: Is the result the same if you are running the Scheduler task manually as if you are running it through Cronjob/CLI? If so, this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it seems to be the same!

Answer (score 0):

Transferring Umlaut files with Coda/Transmit destroys the UTF-8-Filename on a certain level, so PHP can't read them anymore (still showing up with the full filename though in the FTP app). Only using scp now.